# Memory leaks with ARC in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

[image]

I am working on a project and I decided to check leaks in my app.It shows all kinds of leaks on a single page.So,I read about memory leaks and got a fair idea of how the leak checker works.

But here,as you can see,there are leaks that are not relevant to my code.What to do about these leaks?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? There might be memory leaks in Foundation on a simulator.

Comment: yes i'm testing on the device

Comment: Don't worry about leaks that aren't traceable to your code.  Under ARC, the only leaks you should get are from keeping references you've forgotten about, or from using `malloc()` without `free()`.

Comment: @Avi Thanks a lot!!!Are these irrelevant leaks fixed automatically?Where do they come from?Can you elaborate?

Comment: those are memory leaks by framework's, it is clearly showing in "responsible library" if it is not your library then u don't need to worry about, indeed u can't fix it also, just focus on leaks by your app, the "app name" is displayed in the responsible library column just see those leaks